# How to break process in Termius Software?

Tags: ssh, iterm2, secure-crt, termius

I use termius software as a ssh tools in MacBookPro, But I don't know how to break process in Termius Software?
[image]

It has been stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to break on Termius on Mac.